# getting IO Exception while getting address

Tags: android, location

I am using code to get address.But it working fine with while displaying latitude and longitude. I actually want address from it which is i am not getting from it.If anybody has a nice suggestion please.. I am using following code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
 GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
 GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
 {
  LocationClient mLocationClient;
  private TextView addressLabel;
  private TextView locationLabel;
  private Button getLocationBtn;
  private Button disconnectBtn;
  private Button connectBtn;

   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  locationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);
  addressLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressLabel);
  getLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLocation);

  getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        displayCurrentLocation();
     }
  });
  disconnectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);  
  disconnectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        locationLabel.setText("Got disconnected....");
     }
  });
  connectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);  
  connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
        locationLabel.setText("Got connected....");
     }
  });   
  // Create the LocationRequest object
  mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);   
       }    
       @Override
       protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     // Connect the client.
     mLocationClient.connect();
    locationLabel.setText("Got connected....");
   }
  @Override
     protected void onStop() {
     // Disconnect the client.
     mLocationClient.disconnect();
     super.onStop();
     locationLabel.setText("Got disconnected....");
        }

     @Override
     public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
     // Display the connection status
     Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDisconnected() {
     // Display the connection status
     Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
     // Display the error code on failure
     Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failure : " + 
     connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

       public void displayCurrentLocation() {
       // Get the current location's latitude & longitude
       Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
       String msg = "Current Location: " +
       Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude()) + "," +
       Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude());

  // Display the current location in the UI
  locationLabel.setText(msg);

  // To display the current address in the UI
  (new GetAddressTask(this)).execute(currentLocation);
     }
   /*
    * Following is a subclass of AsyncTask which has been used to get
    * address corresponding to the given latitude & longitude.
    */
   private class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String>{
     Context mContext;
     public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
     super();
     mContext = context;
  }

  /*
   * When the task finishes, onPostExecute() displays the address. 
   */
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
     // Display the current address in the UI
     addressLabel.setText(address);
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
     Geocoder geocoder =
     new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
     // Get the current location from the input parameter list
     Location loc = params[0];
     // Create a list to contain the result address
     List<Address> addresses = null;
     try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
        loc.getLongitude(), 1);
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", 
        "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        // Error message to post in the log
        String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
        Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
        " , " +
        Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
        " passed to address service";
        Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return errorString;
     }
     // If the reverse geocode returned an address
     if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        // Get the first address
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        /*
        * Format the first line of address (if available),
        * city, and country name.
        */
        String addressText = String.format(
        "%s, %s, %s",
        // If there's a street address, add it
        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
        address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
        // Locality is usually a city
        address.getLocality(),
        // The country of the address
        address.getCountryName());
        // Return the text
        return addressText;
     } else {
        return "No address found";
     }
  }
  }// AsyncTask class
  }
```

[image: its the thing i am getting]

Comment: What's the IOException Error you are getting saying ?

Comment: What's the error ? Please give some logcat...

Comment: this is the thing i am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Address> addresses = null;
```

try making it List addresses=new ArrayList();

Comment: you mean List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I've written it but it isn't shown. Don't know why. :)

Comment: copy paste for the LogCat the error you're receiving and the line.

Comment: there is no error..i just want to receive address from lat long...but its showing this exception